# Class instance template syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Whilst looking through some code I have found the following syntax:

```
template<class X>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename Z>
    void func()
    {
        Z as;
        as++; 
    }
};

void f()
{
   A<int> obj;
   obj.template func<int>();
}
```

Is there any reason or good practice for `obj.template func<int>()` ? I would usually just go for `obj.func<int>()` Is this some new syntax in c++11/14/17/20?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. yes the question is answered in the suggested link. sorry I didn't find it before asking.